# how to get bitmap from url with using authorization header?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, header, authorization

I tried `picasso` and `volley` but it is very troublesome to get an image from url. How to add auth header with token to get bitmap in asynctask?

Comment: What have you tried? I know it's possible to give an OkHttp instance to Picasso. Maybe you can change the headers of the OkHttp instance?

Answer (score 0):

Just call it and then use the picasso instance, here I add an access token. But you could also add username and password.

```
private void setupPicasso()
{        

    final Context c = context;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    String token = <token you got when you logged in>;
                    String authString = "Bearer "+token;                        
                    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", authString)
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                }
            })
            .build();
    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
            .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the dependencies please